# Pandas column has no values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, series

So I am trying to create a new column for a dataframe that in essence has a 1 when the mfi is over 70 and a 0 when it is not. The code so far is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#get stock prices
d = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\B1880\Downloads\AMD_stock_data\AMD_2020_2020.txt")
d.columns = ['Dates', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']
d.set_index(d['Dates'], inplace=True)
d.drop(['Dates'], axis=1, inplace=True)

#MONEY FLOW INDEX
d['typical_price'] = (d['High'] + d['Low'] + d['Close'])/3 
d['raw_money_flow'] = d['typical_price']*d['Volume']
mf = d.raw_money_flow.diff(1) 
p = mf.copy()
n = mf.copy()
p[p<=0] = 0
n[n>0] = 0
pmf = p.rolling(window=14).mean()
nmf = abs(n.rolling(window=14).mean())
mfr = pmf / nmf
d['mfi'] = 100 - (100 / (mfr +1))
d['mfi'].dropna(inplace=True)

# # #mfi location
d['mfi_70_overbought'] = np.where(d['mfi'] > 70, 1, 0)
d['mfi_70_overbought']
```

When I run the code like this I get the error `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`, and to fix this I did `d['mfi_70_overbought'] = pd.Series(np.where(d['mfi'] > 70, 1, 0))`. Though now when I print the `d['mfi_70_overbought']` column, the entire column is filled with NAN values. What am I missing given that the mfi certainly has values over 70? Thank You!

EDIT: This is what the d['mfi'] prints for output:

```
Dates
2010-01-04 07:18:00          NaN
2010-01-04 07:23:00          NaN
2010-01-04 07:29:00          NaN
2010-01-04 07:38:00          NaN
2010-01-04 07:44:00          NaN
                         ...    
2019-12-31 19:55:00    54.775561
2019-12-31 19:56:00    49.240351
2019-12-31 19:57:00    54.346136
2019-12-31 19:58:00    86.883785
2019-12-31 19:59:00    50.210623
Name: mfi, Length: 1293557, dtype: float64
```

The URL for the data is : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uxVjEJkEmDZwu44pNxsg5ZBonqbTFak8HoESbxo0AM0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: pandas aligns on the Index. So because you `d.set_index(d['Dates'], inplace=True)` and the Series you create has the basic RangeIndex nothing aligns so everything gets set to `NaN`. That being said, the `where` should work, so not sure what's going on

Comment: @ALollz Thank you for responding, Is there another way to set the Dates as the index without receiving this problem?

Comment: I don't think setting the index is the issue. I think the problem is that you slice out parts of the DataFrame, then manipulate, slice and dropna on them separately, all of which have the possibility of changing the shape. I would expect `d['mfi']` to be the shape shape as `d['mfi_70_overbought']` if they are in the same DataFrame, but without sample data it's really hard to know for sure where everything is breaking.

Comment: I have added above what the mfi colum prints. How is it that, the MFI column can print data though the d['mfi_70_overbought'] column can't? Or again is it hard to tell without data? Is there a way I can provide sample data so you guys can see the dataset?

Comment: You can upload the dataset onto google drive and share the link for us to have a try

Comment: Here is the URL: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uxVjEJkEmDZwu44pNxsg5ZBonqbTFak8HoESbxo0AM0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: data is protected, cant download therefore cant test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# necessary imports
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

---

## Setup

*trying to reproduce what you did*

Mock data:

```
data = {'timestep1': [45,46,47,48,1000],
        'timestep2': [46,47,48,49,2020],
        'timestep3': [47,48,49,50,1002],
        'timestep4': [50,49,48,47, 99],
        'timestep5': [45,40,50,70,2500]}
```

Name columns, set index:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
df.columns = ['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']
df.index.name = 'Dates'
```

Make calculations:

```
df['typical_price'] = (df['High'] + df['Low'] + df['Close'])/3 
df['raw_money_flow'] = df['typical_price']*df['Volume']
mf = df.raw_money_flow.diff(1)

p = mf.copy()
n = mf.copy()    
p[p<=0] = 0
n[n>0] = 0

windowsize=2  # example value
pmf = p.rolling(window=windowsize).mean()
nmf = abs(n.rolling(window=windowsize).mean())     
mfr = pmf/nmf

df['mfi'] = 100 - (100 / (mfr +1))    
df['mfi'].dropna(inplace=True)
```

---

## The Problem

Now if I run `df['mfi_70_overbought'] = np.where(df['mfi'] > 70, 1, 0)`, I get the same error: `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`

---

## The Solution

If you just want to have a new column which is *1 when the mfi is over 70 and a 0 when it is not*, then you can avoid `numpy` and use `pandas` tools.

Define a function which returns `1` if its input is greater than `70`, else it should return `0`:

```
def above70(num):
    return int(num > 70)
```

[Apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) this to `df[mfi]`:

```
df['mfi'].apply(above70)
```

In my example case this new column will look like:

```
Dates
timestep3    0
timestep4    0
timestep5    1
Name: mfi, dtype: int64
```

---

## Side Issues

This new column is shorter than the columns of the original dataframe (difference being `windowsize`), because previously we have applied [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) and [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html). Pad this column if you want to attach it to the dataframe, or don't do the steps making it shorter.

Comment: Thank You so much @zabpo, for all your help as well with your help on the other questions